# Kentico 10 - Web Part content change via database

Tags: kentico

i was trying to understand in the Kentico's database model how can i change the web parts content using a database script.

So, basically i have a website based on Kentico with several articles, and internal hyperlinks in its content. But the problem is that the format of those hyperlinks are actually invalid. And i was looking for a way to build a script and do a bulk-update in order to replace some characters and update those hyperlinks to the valid format.

Any idea how can i build the query to get the content of all web parts used in all published pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your web parts and how the content is rendered.  There are different ways that web parts render their content:

- The [web part layout](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/using-custom-web-part-layouts) is used for markup
- The [ASCX file for the web part](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/creating-new-web-parts) is used for markup
- The web part makes use of a repeater that uses a Transformation to render the markup- The markup is generated in code behind

The last one can be tricky to change depending on the web part and whether you have access to all the code behind, but the others you can change either in code in your solution or within the Administration area itself.

Doing this in SQL would probably require a combination of T-SQL XML support and regular expressions to find what you're looking for.  you effectively need to look in the `CMS_WebPart` and `CMS_WebPartLayout` tables to find what you're looking for.

**However**, reading your query, I'm not 100% sure you're talking about web parts, (my apologies if you are) as you talk about links in the article content itself. If these are set using the  *Editable text* web part, then you need to look in the `CMS_Document` table at the `DocumentContent` field to find the links to replace.  But you then need to look at how to correctly format those links going forward so that you do not need to repeat this process later.

---

**Note:**

1. You need to be really careful when doing this in SQL to make sure that you don't create invalid XML.  Things go bad when you do that.
2. This won't flush your cache, so you'll need to clear your cache manually afterwards.
3. If you're using out-of-the-box web parts, you should really make a copy of them and use the copy if you're going to modify, this way, you're less likely to have pain in future upgrades.

Comment: So, i looked into it in order to understand what was done, since i did not develop the solution, but these web parts are widgets in the pages. So the users are using a custom widget with a content field that will receive content or html content. So, as far as i understood, based on this [url](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/what-is-the-difference-between-webpart-and-widget), the widget is a specific type of web part. Am i able to get the widget's properties content in the database?

Comment: So then it gets a little more tasty.  You can look at the `CMS_Document` table in the `DocumentContent` field to find what you're looking.  This is true _unless_ the widgets are inline widgets that you edit on the *Form* tab.  if that is the case, then you need to identify the underlying table in the database for the Page Type.

It may help to look at the [page database structure](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api/page-database-structure) documentation to get a clearer view.

Comment: Hey @mnield, i checked and the DocumentContent is empty, but actually you help me figure out. So, i noticed that the DocumentWebparts columns, that stores all the references for all webparts used in the page, has the webpart reference there, and inclusively the properties and its values. So i was able to find the "widget" used in the page to include the content, and also the content is stored in this column. It is fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically "content" is **not** set in a webpart.  Webparts are configured to retrieve content from page types.  There is an exception to this with specific webparts like Editable Text, Static Text, Static HTML, etc.

The configuration of a webpart is stored at the template level in the `cms_pagetemplate` table.  The configuration for ALL webparts on that page template are stored in the `PageTemplateWebParts` field.  So you'd have to parse through the XML and get the proper webpart and then perform an update on that field.  You maybe able to do a regex to find that content and replace it as well.

Not ideal to do this via SQL simply because of version history and it can cause a lot of problems later on.  I'd suggest finding out which API calls you can make to perform these updates and write a small program for it.

Comment: So, in the website's CMS, the component is called as a widget, but basically it contains a property called "content" where the content editors can write normal content, as you can do via e.g. word, or they can turn on the source view, and see the content translated to HTML. These widgets are associated to pages, and these pages are created using a custom template. So is it the kind of "Editable Text" webpart that you mentioned?

Comment: It's as @mnield stated in his comment to his answer, it gets a bit more complicated now with widgets.  Widgets are stored at the page level and not the template level so you need to look at every page.  Not to mention if you have versioning and workflow enabled, you will need to perform a checkout of the page, perform the update and check the page back in.  This process via SQL is NASTY.  Which is why I suggested using the API to perform your actions.  The type of widget doesn't matter, the fact that it's a widget at all complicates it.